# How to update address of multiple records

Tags: user-expectation, data-entry, edit

I am working on a token generating web application where resellers can buy tokens and sell them to customers.

The business goal is:

- one order can have single or multiple tokens
- multiple tokens can have same address or different addresses
- user can update address for single token
- user can update address for multiple tokens in bulk and they want to see the attached address for each token

Updating single record with address is easy and i'm doing it as show below(first three screens). The issue with multiple address.

How to show multiple addresses for a set of data, we cannot break the range into single tokens as they can be in thousands. Hence breaking down range into rows is not a viable solution.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should move your `Update Address` on the toolbar of token number list at the top.

If there are many:

1. provide selection option (check boxes on the first column). Because, user may need to change selective address change.
2. After selection enable `Update Address` button on the tool bar and let user change address for selected Tokens.
3. In popup, you should mention the number of token for which User taking action.

If there is one record

1. Show one record selected and enable `Update Address` button after loading.

We should always think of list(many records) first while designing. One record is a special case of it.

Comment: the issue is- tokens can be in thousands and can have same/different address.  showing multiple records with different address in pagination and then doing bulk operation is confusing for customer. Thanks btw

Comment: Then, you need to provide more such filters which enable user to list exact those tokens which needs address updates.